# Why does my program produce correct output when my vector< vector< vector<int> > > is larger than the RAM?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, ram

I have implemented a system which takes as an input some data, and produces as a result a very big `vector< vector< vector<int> > >` which I then output to a file.

After calculating the result I decided to count the total amount of numbers inside this final 3d vector and it was: `1386502951`

that means that the total amount of memory needed to store this vector is at least `1386502951*4 bytes = 5.16512599 GB`

however my RAM memory is only 4 GB.

Can someone explain to me how this is possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the magic of Virtual memory/paging?

Comment: Virtual memory strikes again.

Comment: What operating system?  (The two-word answer is "virtual memory", but we can explain in more detail if you answer that question.)

Comment: I'm using the latest Ubuntu

Comment: it's 64 bit. I knew some things about virtual memory but didn't know it is used in vectors, very interesting.

Comment: In a nutshell, your OS is presumably "swapping" some of the vector data onto the disk while you're working on other parts of the vector, then loading it back into RAM when you need to do more work on it.  The way this is transparently coordinated is known as "virtual memory".  It normally relies on having a "virtual address space" large enough to handle the amount of data involved - which for >4GB would normally mean 64-bit addresses which are only supported by "64 bit" Operating Systems.

Comment: "didn't know it is used in vectors" - it's used for anything at all... static data arrays, dynamic memory for vectors, maps, lists, your own data types.  The C++ libraries don't have to code anything to get this support - it's all transparently coordinated by the CPU and Operating System.

Comment: @TonyD You should post an answer so I can upvote

Comment: @jozefg: I'm feeling lazy this morning... ;-)  Besides which, I'm only elaborating on what's already been said in comments above... googling virtual memory would have got you the same insights - I've no desire to accept points for that.

Comment: @TonyD Fair enough :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application is able to allocate more memory than is physically installed on your computer because it supports virtual memory. Allocation, paging and releasing virtual memory is handled by the operating system to allow your application to run without having to worry about exhausting physical memory.

Keep in mind that releasing the allocated memory may not occur immediately when your application frees memory from it's heap. This has a tendency to make people think their application is at times using more memory that it should.

There are a good number of websites that discuss the topic of virtual and physical and any API's provided by the operating that allow you to have some control over it. A quick Google Dance should provide you with a significant number of links on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

There could be a number of reason that this does not fail.

As stated in comments, the most likely is that windows is putting a large chunk of it in Virtual Memory (not RAM).

Another option (under some circumstances) is that the optimiser is cleaning up your list (maybe?)

The best way to see exactly what is happening is to open task manager and switch to the Performance tab and look at the RAM monitors it uses.